# Differentiation of functions defined by Borel measures.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

My question has to do with a detail in the proof of the following:

Let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb R$, and let $F : \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$  be defined
by $F(x) =\mu ((−∞,x]).$ If $\mu$ is differentiable at $a$, then $F$ is differentiable at $a$, and $F'(a) = (D\mu)(a)$ where

$$D\mu(a)=\limsup_{\epsilon \downarrow 0}\left \{ \frac{\mu (I))}{\lambda (I)}: a\in I; |I|<\epsilon\right \}.$$

The proof goes as follows:

if $x<a$ then $\frac{F(x)-F(a)}{x-a}=\frac{\mu ([a,x])}{\lambda ([a,x])}$  whereas  $\frac{F(x)-F(a)}{x-a}=\frac{\mu ((a,x])}{\lambda ((a,x])}$ if $x>a.$

In the first case, we have $$D\mu(a)=\limsup_{\epsilon \downarrow 0^-}\left \{ \frac{\mu ([a,x])}{\lambda ([a,x])}: a\in I; |I|<\epsilon\right \}=\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{F(x)-F(a)}{x-a}.$$

In the second case, we want to assert that

$$D\mu(a)=\limsup_{\epsilon \downarrow 0^+}\left \{ \frac{\mu ([a,x])}{\lambda ([a,x])}: a\in I; |I|<\epsilon\right \}=\lim_{x\to a^{+}}\frac{F(x)-F(a)}{x-a}$$

and then the result is immediate.

But this is not quite right because the intervals above (when $x>a$) are $\it{half-open}.$ Now it is pretty obvious that these intervals can be approximated to any desired degree of accuracy by considering intervals of the form $[a+1/n,x]$ so I am looking for a rigorous way to work this into the definition of $D\mu.$ Maybe along these lines:

If $D\mu(a)=d$ then for all $r >0,$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\ \left |  \frac{\mu([a,x])}{\lambda([a,x])}-d \right |<r$ whenever $x-a<\epsilon.$ Then for each integer $n$  such that $a+1/n<x$ we have  $x-(a+1/n)=x-1/n-a<\epsilon$ and  then, $\left |\frac{\mu([a+1/n,x])}{\lambda([a+1/n,x])}  -d\right |<r.$ Since this is true for all integers $n$ such that $a+1/n<x$, the result follows.

On the other hand, since $\mu$ is differentiable at $a$ we must have $\mu (\left \{ a \right \})=0, $ so perhaps it is as easy as noting that $[a,x]=(a,x]\cup \left \{ a \right \}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I think it is your second proof. I am assuming that $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Then given $\eta>0$ there is $\varepsilon$ such that
$$\left\vert\frac{\mu(I)}{\lambda(I)}-D\mu(a)\right\vert\le \eta$$
for every interval $I$ with $a\in I$ and $|I|<\varepsilon$. Take $I=[a,a+\frac1n)$ then 
$$0\le\mu(\{a\})\le\mu([a,a+1/n))\le  (D\mu(a)+\eta)\lambda([a,a+1/n))=(D\mu(a)+\eta)\frac1n\to 0.$$
So $\mu(\{a\})=0$ as you said.